# Change the Colour of a value in a SQL Server DB Mail

Tags: html, css, sql, t-sql, conditional-formatting

I have created a DB Mail alert that sends out a HTML formatted table showing the pass or fail status of my SQL agents.

The alert works well, but the user has request an additional change where they want conditional formating on Pass/Fail status of the data, where failed status is to be highlighted RED and pass status to be highlighted GREEN.

Is this possible to achieve to in SQL using DB Mail and HTML formatting? 
A few forums have stated that JavaScript may need to be used but I'm not sure if its possible to even us JS in SQL.

My code is below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------- Declare Variables ---------------------- 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Declare @email_body nvarchar(max)
Declare @email_profile_name nvarchar(max)
Declare @email_recipients nvarchar(max)
Declare @email_subject nvarchar(max)
Declare @tableHTML nvarchar(MAX) = ''
Declare @Style nvarchar(MAX) = ''
Declare @Textdate nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @crlf nvarchar = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
Declare @Server nvarchar(max)


----------------------------------------------------------------------------            
--------------------------- Set Varriables (That should not change) --------        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
set @Server = @@SERVERNAME
set @Textdate = cast(getdate() as date)
Set @email_subject = @Textdate + ': Morning SQL Server Checks'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
----------------------------------- Set Varriables (User Input) ------------ 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--Add other Email addresses as needed. Seperate with Semi-colon (;)
set @email_recipients = 'Email@Email.com'


---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------- Create Temp Tables --------------------- 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Results
Create table #Results (
    [Server] nvarchar(max),
    [Entity] nvarchar(max),
    [Status] nvarchar(max),
    [Message] nvarchar(max),
    [Type] nvarchar(max))


----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
----------------------------------- Generate Data -------------------------- 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--Gets SQL Agent Results (Script Derived from here: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/534cc5be-0021-4766-    
9eef-92fea819e2e3/script-to-get-sql-server-agent-job-schedule-and-the-last- 
run-status?forum=sqldatabaseengine)
Insert into #Results
SELECT @@SERVERNAME as 'Server Name'
      ,J.Name AS 'Job Name' 
      --,CASE J.Enabled  WHEN 1 THEN 'Yes' WHEN 0 THEN 'No' END as 'Job     
 Enabled'
      ,CASE WHEN LASTRUN.run_status = 0 THEN 'Failed'
            WHEN LASTRUN.run_status = 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
            WHEN LASTRUN.run_status = 2 THEN 'Retry'
            WHEN LASTRUN.run_status = 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
            ELSE 'Unknown' END as 'Last Run Status'                           
      ,LASTRUN.message as 'Last Run Message'
      ,'SQL Agent Jobs' as 'Type'
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs J LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules JS ON     
J.job_id = JS.job_id
               LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysschedules S ON JS.schedule_id = S.schedule_id
               LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT J1.job_id
                                      ,J1.RUN_DURATION
                                      ,J1.run_date
                                      ,J1.run_time
                                      ,J1.message
                                      ,J1.run_status
                                 FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory J1
                                 WHERE instance_id = (SELECT MAX(instance_id) 
                                                      FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory J2 
                                                      WHERE J2.job_id = J1.job_id)) LASTRUN ON J.job_id = LASTRUN.job_id
where J.Enabled = 1 --Only check for agents that have been enabled 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
----------------------------------- Generate Email ------------------------- 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--Set Style (CSS)
SET @Style += +N'<style type="text/css">' + N'.tg  {border-    
 collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aaa;}'
+ N'.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}'
+ N'.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;background-color:#f38630;}'
+ N'.tg .tg-9ajh{font-weight:bold;background-color:#68cbd0}' + N'.tg .tg-hgcj{font-weight:bold;text-align:center}'
+ N'</style>';

 --Set Email Output (HTML Layout)
 Set @tableHTML += @Style + @tableHTML + N'<H1 style="color:Blue;">' + 
 @Textdate + ': Morning SQL Server Checks</H1>' +
                                    N'<H2>' + @Server + '</H2>' +
                                    N'<H3>Databases</H3>' +
+ N'<table class="tg">' --DEFINE TABLE

-- Define Headers for Database Check
+ N'<tr>'
+ N'<H3>SQL Agents</H3>' +
+ N'<table class="tg">' --DEFINE TABLE

+ N'<tr>'
+ N'<td class="tg-9ajh">Server</td>'
+ N'<td class="tg-9ajh">Entity</td>' 
+ N'<td class="tg-9ajh">Status</td>'
+ N'<td class="tg-9ajh">Message</td>'
+ N'<td class="tg-9ajh">Type</td></tr>'

-- Define data for SQL Agent and cast to xml
+ Cast((
        Select td = isnull([Server],'###')
              ,''
              ,td = isnull([Entity],'###')
              ,''
              ,td = isnull([Status],'###')
              ,''
              ,td = isnull([Message],'###')
              ,''
              ,td = isnull([Type],'###')
              ,''
        from #Results
        where [type] = 'SQL Agent Jobs' FOR
         XML PATH('tr') ,
             TYPE
       ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
       + N'</table>'; 

-- Send the Email 
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'Outlook Support Profile', 
     @recipients = @email_recipients,
     @body = @tableHTML,
     @body_format = 'HTML',
     @subject = @email_subject 

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------- Cleanup --------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
drop table #Results
```

I hope the code is clear enough and makes sense.

Thanks you
Anthony

Comment: The question comes essentially down to "Is it possible to have different background colors for different table rows or cells (or other areas) in HTML?". The answers is "Yes.". Look at the `bgcolor` attribute of `tr` or `td` for the quick and dirty old school way or use CSS/inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar with my dbmail audit emails to differentiate between production and non-production instances.

The method I use is to predefine the style information and then use a unique value in the body string to identify where the style needs to be applied. In your case the unique values we can use are `<td>Failed` and `<td>Succeeded`. By doing a replace on those values to a version that includes the style, you should get a table with your conditional formatting.

I made the following two changes to your script and ran it against one of my test instances. It looks like it should get you where you want.

First, update the style section:

```
--Set Style (CSS)
SET @Style += +N'<style type="text/css">' + N'.tg  {border-    
 collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#aaa;}'
+ N'.tg .green{background-color: green; color:white;}'
+ N'.tg .red{background-color: red; color:white;}'
+ N'.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}'
+ N'.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#aaa;color:#fff;background-color:#f38630;}'
+ N'.tg .tg-9ajh{font-weight:bold;background-color:#68cbd0}' + N'.tg .tg-hgcj{font-weight:bold;text-align:center}'
+ N'</style>';
```

After @tableHTML is built, add a REPLACE to shove the style formatting into the generated table:

```
SELECT @tableHTML = REPLACE(REPLACE(@tableHTML,N'<td>Failed',N'<td class="Red">Failed'),N'<td>Succeeded',N'<td class="green">Succeeded')
```